# Flutter firebase_messaging 6.0.9 how to record push notifications into database - sqflite: 1.2.0

Tags: flutter

I have built an application and used firebase messaging package together with firebase cloud notifications. The notifications arrive and I am happy with that part. What I am also trying to do is to store those notifications to the database and provide a user with a handy section listing all those previous notifications directly inside of the app.

For the database, I am using the SQLite package which I was able to set up with no issues. I have made tests and it works (I have created store, update, delete procedures).

Now I am trying to connect those two together. So, upon iOS receiving the notification, I would like to run one of those procedures to store the notification inside of the database. However, it does not seem to be working and I am not sure what I am not grasping here. My code looks like this, just so you get the idea:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thw/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:thw/screens/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:thw/widgets/widgetNotifications.dart';
import 'package:thw/services/db.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'dart:io';

Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic notification = message['data'];
    print(notification);
    await DbModel().dbOpen();
    await DbModel().dbInsert(notification['title'], notification['body']);

  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    print(notification);
    await DbModel().dbOpen();
    await DbModel().dbInsert(notification['title'], notification['body']);
  }
}

class NotificationsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationsScreenState createState() => _NotificationsScreenState();
}

class _NotificationsScreenState extends State<NotificationsScreen> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  List notifications;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifications = [];
    getAllNotifications();


... more code
```

I have added this code on every single screen. I have loading, main screen and notifications screen. But this part does not seem to be working:

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic notification = message['data'];
    print(notification);
    await DbModel().dbOpen();
    await DbModel().dbInsert(notification['title'], notification['body']);

  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    print(notification);
    await DbModel().dbOpen();
    await DbModel().dbInsert(notification['title'], notification['body']);
  }
}
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong? Am I having a bad grasp of how this works? The notifications arrive, but the part with the dbOpen and dbInsert never seems to run.

Comment: also facing the same issue, hope you found  a solution.

Comment: @b.john I haven't till this day, the project is on hold